# Google App Engine Cron Job Succeeds but does nothing?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I have a Python Cron job that, according to the Logs, runs to completion without errors.  However, none of the "logging.error()" messages I have included in the code are included in the log and none of the required processing is done.

So that I can run this manually, I have a link in my HTML menu "Assign Rental Payments Due" that does the processing required and logs error logging messages correctly.

----
Section of app.yaml

```
- url: /rhrentassign.html
  script: frhrentassign.app
```

----
Full cron.yaml

```
cron:

- description: Rental Payments Due
  url: /rhrentassign
  schedule: every day 14:00
```

----
Full python code (file is frhrentassign.py)

```
import os
import logging
import webapp2

from CronRH import *

class rhrentassignhandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        swork = trhrenttopaycron()
        swork.allnamespaces()

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/rhrentassign.html', rhrentassignhandler)], debug=True)
```

----
Any thoughts on what I have done wrong would be most appreciated.
Many Thanks, David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your handler is mapped to '/rhrentassign.html', but the cron is going to '/rhrentassign'.

Generally unless you have a very very good reason, there's no need to put 'html' in route names.

Comment: Thanks for both your pointers.  The trick was, indeed, that the urls are all the same: app.yaml, cron.yaml and my menu link.<br/>